# Advanced ApplicationBar background color? (Windows Phone 8)

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8

How do you change the background from a Advanced ApplicationBar? I tried this but it stays black.

```
 <Sh:AdvancedApplicationBar Background="Gray">
                        <Grid>
                            <Sh:AdvancedApplicationBarIconButton Text="edit"
                                                                 IconUri="/Assets/ActionBarButtons/btn_actionbar_edit.png"
                                                                 Command="{Binding EditCommand}"
                                                                 VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />
                        </Grid>
                </Sh:AdvancedApplicationBar>
```

Answer (score 0):

replace `<Sh:AdvancedApplicationBar Background="Gray">` by `<Sh:AdvancedApplicationBar BackgroundColor="Gray">`

Comment: I tried that before and then i get a NullReferenceException error.

Answer (score 0):

I found it out, it is a wrapper arround the normal Appbar so you need to do this:

```
 <phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
    <shell:ApplicationBar BackgroundColor="Gray"
                          Opacity="0.5" />
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.ApplicationBar>
```